# git difftool problem: not setting LOCAL, REMOTE variables

Tags: git, difftool

According to doc and various answers here git difftool will invoke the specified executable (usually a shell script) with environment variables LOCAL and REMOTE set to the file paths. But when I try, LOCAL and REMOTE are not set. I've tried the following test:

```
git config --global diff.tool mytest  
git config --global difftool.mytest.cmd mytest.sh  
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

with mytest.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh  
echo "LOCAL:$LOCAL REMOTE:$REMOTE"
```

invoking:

```
git difftool --tool mytest <commitid> -- <path-to-file>
```

output:

```
LOCAL: REMOTE:
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the man page means is that difftool.<tool>.cmd can have `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE` in its command-line.  Those will be replaced with the relevant file paths.  It isn't intended that those variables are exported into your environment.

To demonstrate with an example, here's a re-worked version of your original setup.

```
git config --global diff.tool mytest  
git config --global difftool.mytest.cmd 'mytest.sh $LOCAL $REMOTE'
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the diff wrapper I've always used (with tkdiff):

```
#!/bin/sh

# diff is called with 7 parameters:
# path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode

tkdiff "$2" "$5"
```

Which uses parameters rather than `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE`.

Comment: I've tried that, $1, $2, etc are not set either. Anyway from the docs that invocation is used for "git diff" configured with external tool, not for "git difftool"